# Getting insights data from LinkedIn and Twitter

Tags: linkedin, twitter-api

Is there any way to get insights data from Twitter and LinkedIn company/brand pages as Facebook provides?

**Data like:**

- negative feedback;
- comment/wall posts;
- likes, shares, follows, re-tweets etc

**And insights like:**

- Monthly active users;
- Page views;
- User demographics etc

Comment: Could you be more specific? What kind of data did you expect?

Comment: @JMax : Please see my updated answer for details

Comment: THen, the answer is no. You will have different information (members, new company, ...). This is related to the heart of each social network (facebook = friends, LinkeIn = collegues)

Comment: @JMax :Thanks, but please can u please explain more?

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, you won't get the same information from LinkedIn than Facebook.

As LinkedIn is more a *professional* social network, you are more likely to get information about who works there, what they have done before, where they live and so on.

Here is an example with MS: http://www.linkedin.com/company/microsoft/employee-insights?trk=tabs_biz_employee_insights

See what it gives:

[image]

Comment: Actaully I have done R & D and realized same that we can't get insights as facebook here. But just want to be sure

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part but I don't understand what you want to do with the Twitter API to retrieve these information

Comment: In my application I have to aggregate user insights,responses, likes, posts,page views etc from social media like linkedin,facebook,twitter for a company/brand page at a central database. After that I have to analyze and visualize that data

Comment: Ok, I understand but I don't think you will get much information from Twitter as a Twitter account from a company is not much different from any other. Btw, I don't think Twitter aggregate any information about companies so I don't know what you could retrieve.